# Dynamically adding meta title and description to views in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, meta-title

I am looking for a function to add meta title and description when I enter and call values ​​in view at .net core. I have tried the following code but it did not.How do I include HtmlMeta and Page? Does this code work for me? I am waiting for your help.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "Your Page Title";

        HtmlMeta metaDescription = new HtmlMeta();
        metaDescription.Name = "description";
        metaDescription.Content = "Your Page Description";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaDescription);

        HtmlMeta metaKeywords = new HtmlMeta();
        metaKeywords.Name = "keywords";
        metaKeywords.Content = "Your Page Keywords";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaKeywords);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the layout page add new section inside `<head>` tags:

```html
<head>
...
@await RenderSectionAsync("Header", required: false)
</head>
```

Then you can add meta tags to the header section from any view:

```html
@section Header {
    <meta name="description" content="@Model.Description"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Model.KeyWords"/>
}
```

In your page model you can provide the values for `Description` and `KeyWords` then pass it to the view.